# List<T> without Where in the intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, resharper

I don't understand why sometime I can't perform a `.where()` on a generic list. Most of the time it's shown in the intellisense, but sometimes it's not.

Is it related to the fact that the list is a parameter? Or is it related to resharper's intellisense?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import the appropriate namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I see you're using Resharper, you could get into the delegate's body and VS/R# will then prompt you to import. ie, list.Where(i => i. <-- when I hit '.' I get the import suggestion.

Comment: You can use "Import symbol" completion (see ReSharper | Edit | Import symbol, note shortcut there) after the dot to show all applicable extension methods regardless of imported namespaces. ReSharper will insert using directive as necesssary.

Comment: I always use smart complete(shift+alt+space) to get Resharper to import the Linq namespace.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

Without that, LINQ extension methods will not show up.